# how to do chain functions in Spark dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

how to do chain functions in Spark dataframe ? in my code, I want to do upper case first and then do a boolean conversion. but my code didn't work. Thanks

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val trimStr: String => String = _.trim
val trimUDF = udf(trimStr)

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val upperCaseStr: String => String = _.toUpperCase
val upperCaseUDF = udf(upperCaseStr)

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
     def booleanValueSubstitution = udf[String, String] {
       case "" => "N"
       case null => "N"           
       case "TRUE" => "Y"        
     }
var df= df1.withColumn("xx", booleanValueSubstitution(upperCaseUDF(df1("yy"))) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all don't reinvent the wheel. For many common tasks you'll find built-in functions:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{trim, upper}
```

which, among other benefits are `null` safe:

```scala
val df = Seq(None, Some(""), Some("true"), Some(" TRUE "), Some("foo")).toDF("x")

df.select(upper(trim($"x")))
```

```
+--------------+
|upper(trim(x))|
+--------------+
|          null|
|              |
|          TRUE|
|          TRUE|
|           foo|
+--------------+
```

Functions you defined, with an exception of `booleanValueSubstitution`, are not. Every time your code encounters `NULL` it will fail due to NPE so if you decide to reinvent the wheel you should always cover for that.

You can pattern match, as you did with `booleanValueSubstitution`, or you can use `Try`:

```scala
import scala.util.Try

val upperCaseUDF = udf((s: String) => Try(s.toUpperCase).toOption)
val trimUDF = udf((s: String) => Try(s.trim).toOption)
```

If you decide to use pattern matching make sure that conditions are exhaustive:

```scala
val booleanValueSubstitution = udf[String, String] {
  case "" => "N"
  case null => "N"           
  case "TRUE" => "Y"   
  case _ => "N"
}
```

or simpler:

```scala
val booleanValueSubstitution = udf[String, String] {      
  case "TRUE" => "Y"
  case _ => "N"
}
```

Otherwise you'll get `scala.MatchError`.

Next, there exist idiomatic SQL solutions you can use in place of pattern matching with `udf`. You can for example use `CASE WHEN`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{when, coalesce, lit}

df.select(
  when($"x".isNull, "N").when($"x" === "", "N").when($"x" === "TRUE", "Y")
)
```

or:

```
df.select(coalesce(when($"x" === "TRUE", "Y").otherwise("N"), lit("N")))
```

Finally if you think booleans it is better to use booleans:

```scala
when($"x".isNull, false).when($"x" === "", false).otherwise(true)
```

In general:

- Built-in functions are typically preferred over UDF for a number of reasons.
- UDF are not allowed on every position so chaining is not always possible. There are situations when you have to add `udf` result separately:

  ```scala
  df.withColumn("foo", someUDF("x")).withColumn("bar", someFunc("foo"))
  ```